# Android Data size increasing automatically

Tags: android, performance

I have developed an android app. After I install into my mobile it shows size as 5 MB Total. then I start app now my app total consumes 13 MB (5 MB app and 8 MB data)

That app has only 5 basic activity like register, login, change password, profile.

What could be a problem ?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are storing user details in shared preference ?

Comment: yes... I am saving 6 string variables

Comment: check if your app has very large sized images

Comment: so it is size occupied by shared preference and cache

Comment: i am compressing all images using tinypng so size is very less... less than 50 kb

Comment: check your complete directory structure for the files because if you have only 5 Activities then apk size should not be that large

Comment: @VishalPatoliya I am saving only 6 variable in shared preference.. can this 6 variable consumes 8 MB... i am confuse here

Comment: but .when apk is extracted in your phone and other is system default memory occupied by your application

Comment: @indramurari okey i will check out completely and get back to you.

Comment: when I am instaling third party app and during its first run its size is not increased or very less (KB). But in my case it's increasing in MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Very Simple, Following steps can save you !

Step 1 : Click on the build variants from android studio sidebar
Step 2 : Select your module 
Step 3 : Set build variant as a release.

That's It

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks a lot. You help me a lot.